# If $A\subseteq B$ and $B\subseteq C$ then $A\subseteq C$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

can someone please correct me if i made some mistakes here on ma solution.
i used Lynx hea
Problem D

1.) Give the definition of $S\subseteq T$ for general sets $S$ and $T$.

Solution

The set $S$ is a subset of $T$ if and only if every element of S is also an element of T.

2.) Prove that for all sets $A, B, C$ if $A\subseteq B$ and $B\subseteq C$ then  $A\subseteq C$.

Solution

Suppose that $x\in A$. Because $A\subseteq B$, this implies that $x\in B$ Because $B\subseteq C$ we see that $x\in C$. Because $x \in A$ it implies that $x\in C$. It follows that $A\subseteq C$.

Comment: Greetings. You appear to have gone to great lengths to make a horribly formatted question. Please don't do that. If you need help formatting with basic latex, you'll find the FAQ pretty useful.

Comment: I also switched the five totally irrelevant tags for two relevant ones. Good tagging draws attention of people who can give good answers.

Comment: I just edited the crap out of your post. Don't use $"\backslash,"$ between every word.

Answer (score 1):

Your solutions are both good, but I have a nitpick with the first one:

> You shouldn't define terms using "if and only if."

Ideally you would just use "if" here. The most commonly given reason for this is that making a definition is really a different thing from a biconditional statement. You'll find this is the case for most of the literature.